# Scrolling in a ItemsControl while using a horizontal StackPanel as the ItemsPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have an `ItemsControl`, I've built the items that I'm displaying in it (`views:DisplayGroupView`) in such a way that they will expand horizontally to show all their contents and not vertically (only using the available height)

I've changed my `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl` to use a `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`

Layout wise it's perfect, but no matter what I do I can't get it to scroll horizontally so I can see everything.

This is the XAML for the `ItemsControl`:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayGroups}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="120,20,120,20" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:DisplayGroupView Margin="0,0,20,0" DataContext="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></views:DisplayGroupView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This lays everything out okay, but won't scroll. I've also tried changing the ItemsControls template to include a scrollviewer, but this only stacks things vertically:

```
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                        <ItemsPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
```

How can I get the horizontal layout while still being able to scroll?

Comment: Did you try pulling it out of the Template and embedding it by itself? Like <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"><ItemsControl/></ScrollViewer>, sounds silly I know, but worth a shot.

Comment: @ChrisW. When I do that the ItemsControl uses up more vertical space and no longer lays out the way I want. Even with <ScrollViewer VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">

Comment: @ChrisW. I eventually got it using your suggestion, just took a bit of tweaking with the alignments. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Eh sure why not, I was literally just on here about to post a reply but as long as you got your remedy, I know how frustrating little crap like that can become haha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pull it out of the `ItemsControl` and embed it by itself, for some reason that often acts as a workaround so something like;

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibilty="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl/>
</ScrollViewer>
```